# convert String^ to standard C++ string

Tags: string, visual-c++

I faced a problem `cannot convert parameter from 'System::String ^' to 'std::string'`. How can i convert System::String^ into standard C++ string in Visual C++ environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this link at Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
void MarshalString ( String ^ s, string& os ) {
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
    const char* chars = 
       (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
    os = chars;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}

int main() {
    string a = "test";
    String ^ c = gcnew String("abcd");
    cout << a << endl;
    MarshalString(c, a);
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //*** convert String^ to standard C++ string

 ` String ^SyStr = "abc"; // system string
   string StStr ="";      // standard string
   for each (char c in SyStr )
   {
       StStr .push_back( c);
   } `

   //**** End convert String^ to standard C++ string 

   //****  convert standard C++ string to  String^ 

  ` String ^SyStr = "";  // system string
    string StStr ="xyz"; // standard string
    SyStr = gcnew String(StStr.c_str());`

    //**** End  convert standard C++ string to  String^
```